# Google Maps V3 API for Codeigniter [Adding Numbered Markers + other questions]

Tags: php, google-maps, codeigniter, google-maps-markers

I have several questions regarding the Google Map V3 API and its library for Codeigniter which wraps the PHP class for google maps api.

1. **How can I have the marker show A,B,C… or 1,2,3…?** (most important)
2. How do I prevent the white bubble box from opening up when I click on the marker?
3. After adding a marker using addMarkerByAddress() inside my controller, is there any function that I can call from within the controller to remove the marker? Because after adding directions to it, the marker from addMarkerByAddress() overlaps with the start/end marker in my case so I need to remove the initial marker.
4. I cannot seem to have the map display without calling addMarkerByAddress(), is that right?

This has been bothering me for days so I hope someone can help me out!!

Related Links

- http://www.in-the-attic.co.uk/2010/08/02/codeigniter-google-maps-library-using-google-maps-api-version-3/
- http://www.bradwedell.com/phpgooglemapapi/docs/GoogleMapAPI/GoogleMapAPI.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For showing custom markers use this:

```
var latlon2 = new google.maps.LatLng(44.959944, 26.0186218);
marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({  
            position: latlon2,  
            map: map,  
            icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|FF0000|000000' 
            });
```